# WordPress permalinks rewrite on iis7

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, iis-7, permalinks, hebrew

I spend a lot of time in looking for solution, so you are my last hope before giving up :)

On my localhost iis7 i set custom permalinks http://sitename/%sample-post%/ with rewrite mode installed.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <add value="index.php"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
            <rule name="WordPress: http://tip4u03" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
            </rule></rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Its work only in wwwroot directory. Outside of wwwroot directory, its return 404 template page. Same issue on my shared iis7 server (VPS)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue !!! 
The problem was't with site location, it was because the permalinks are in Hebrew language. I added the following condition to wp-config file

```
if (isset($_SERVER['UNENCODED_URL'])) {
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['UNENCODED_URL'];
}
```

according to this link: [Wordpress Hebrew permalinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25487444/woocommerce-url-with-a-hebrew-word)

Finally its work !